# React - how to pass a prop into a class function call that is then accessed in componentDidMount function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to coding and have spent a long time trying to make this work but I am stuck. I know this is a very basic question and if it is answered elsewhere, I have failed to find the right questions to search to find that answer.

This is from the react tutorial -- it is the automatic timer that self-updates every 1000ms. **I would like to be able to pass a `prop` into the `<Clock />` function call to specify the interval I want that specific object instance to use** like so: `<Clock interval=2000 />`

**Here is the code they provided:**

```js
    function FormattedDate(props) {
      return <h2>It is {props.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h2>;
    }

    class Clock extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {date: new Date()};
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(
          () => this.tick(),
          1000
        );
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.timerID);
      }

      tick() {
        this.setState({
          date: new Date()
        });
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <FormattedDate date={this.state.date} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    function App() {
      return (
        <div>
          <Clock />
          <Clock />
          <Clock />
        </div>
      );
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Here is what I have tried:**

- Setting the state to have `timer: 5000`
- passing it in as a `const` to the function call
- then updating the state in `componentDidMount`

**However, this does not work because I am trying to use a `prop` to update `state`. What am I supposed to do instead?**

Unsuccessful code: (just the bits I've tried)

```js
        this.state = {
          date: new Date(),
          interval: 5000,
        };

    componentDidMount(props){
          () => this.tick(),
          props.timer
        );
      }

    const timer = {
      interval: 5000,
    }

    ReactDOM.render()
      <Clock interval={timer.interval}/>,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Comment: have you looked at getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) ?

Comment: `componentdidmount` doesn't get passed `props`. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount. You need to use `this.props.interval` in CDM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass the interval as a prop you can do it like this:

```
   <Clock interval="1000"/>
```

and access it like this:

```
  componentDidMount() {
        this.timerID = setInterval(
          () => this.tick(),
         this.props.interval
        );
      }
```

You have to use `this.props` to have access to your props in the class components.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. So it was `this` missing from my understanding of the program. 

If I can ask you to confirm my summary of the problem: `componentDidMount()` does not accept props but we can access the `props` passed into the component function because `this` refers to the scope where the `props` were passed in?

Comment: if you want to access the props or the state anywhere in your class component you have to use `this` keyword

Comment: That did not answer my follow-up question but I appreciate that you answered the original. Thank you.